# Unable to install edge on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, 22.04

I have downloaded the Debian packages for edge from Microsoft edge download site https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?exp=e511&form=MA13FJ but for some when I tried installing it I get

```
Couldn't find any package by regex 'microsoft-edge-stable_110.0.1587.41-1_amd64.deb
```

I again tried

```
 sudo apt install microsoft-edge-stable
```

and got

```
Unable to locate package microsoft-edge-stable
```

Is there a way to get around this and install edge.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Edge web browser includes Bing AI with GPT 4. To install Microsoft Edge web browser in Ubuntu open the  terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-stable/microsoft-edge-stable_110.0.1587.41-1_amd64.deb?brand=M102
sudo apt install ./microsoft-edge-stable_110.0.1587.41-1_amd64.deb
```

---

You can also install Microsoft Edge browser as a flatpak app by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak  
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.microsoft.Edge
```

To run Microsoft Edge:

```
flatpak run com.microsoft.Edge
```

Comment: Hi Karel, I tried, but still got an error:  Unsupported file ./microsoft-edge-stable_110.0.1587.41-1_amd64.deb given on commandline

Comment: What size is the file that you downloaded? Mine is 139,680,406 bytes. What happens when you right-click microsoft-edge-stable_110.0.1587.41-1_amd64.deb  and select *Open with other application* -> *Software Install* ?

Comment: same size 139.7 MB (139,680,406 bytes)  opening with Software install I got " Failed to install file: not supported "

Comment: Try running the edited command in my answer.

Comment: Same error "Unsupported file ./microsoft-edge-stable_110.0.1587.41-1_amd64.deb given on commandline">

Comment: I've run out of suggestions. Maybe it's for the best because the ChatGPT integration feature in Bing doesn't work yet either.

Comment: Hi, I've tried again today and the installation was successful. I'm not sure how

Answer (score 0):

I could install the package today just opening the folder with the GUI file browser and clicking on it -so that the synaptic package manager (Linux Mint) opens ist. The installation was successful.
(My only interest in installing edge is also to use the integration with chat gpt in bing.)

Comment: Please edit your answer and clarify what you meant by "package manager opens". Did that open the Ubuntu Software app?

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code on a terminal:

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install microsoft-edge-dev
```

This ensures you import Microsoft GPG key and add the Microsoft Edge repository to your system's sources list.

Answer (score 0):

To install the official Microsoft Edge browser using Flatpak, execute the following commands in your terminal:

```sh
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.microsoft.Edge
```

Choosing Flatpak for the installation instead of directly downloading and installing DEB packages offers advantages. For instance, Flatpak simplifies the update process, making it easier to keep applications like Microsoft Edge up to date with the latest versions.

It's important to note that applications installed via Flatpak are sandboxed, which restricts their access to system files. This restriction can lead to issues, such as the inability to use the drag-and-drop feature or open/view local files. To mitigate this, consider adjusting the default sandbox permissions with these commands:

```sh
flatpak override --user --filesystem=home com.microsoft.Edge
flatpak override --user --filesystem=/media --filesystem=/mnt com.microsoft.Edge
```