# Windowing issue on Ubuntu

Tags: xorg, window, wayland

I used Microsoft Edge on Ubuntu 22.04, and when open edge seems to be the focus of the cursor and thus it takes several clicks to focus on a background window after I click on them while edge is open. Between other apps this doesn't occur. This happens in both x11 and Wayland.

Comment: You can also install Microsoft Edge browser as a flatpak app in Ubuntu by running the commands in the [following answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1454329/).  Does this windowing issue also occur when running Microsoft Edge web browser as a flatpak app?

Comment: The flatpak solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: I posted the suggestion in my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Microsoft Edge browser as a flatpak app by running the following commands and then check if this windowing issue also occurs when running Microsoft Edge web browser as a flatpak app:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak  
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.microsoft.Edge
```

To run Microsoft Edge:

```
flatpak run com.microsoft.Edge
```